Can anyone give an example of a ring $R$ which is simultaneously a vector space over a field $k$ but not an algebra over that field?
If $R$ is a ring and at the same time a vector space over a field $k$ such that scalar multiplication is compatible with ring multiplication i.e.
$c(xy)=(cx)y=x(cy),$, then $R$ is a $k$-algebra.
I am wondering whether there is a ring $R$ with a k-vector space structure where the above type of compatibility does not hold. Can anybody give me such an example ? Thanks in advance.

Well, all vector spaces can be made an algebra by adding a zero product: $xy=0$ for,all $x,y.$

@ThomasAndrews Not relevant here since the ring structure is given. Also, that doesn't have a unit.

@Promit What did you try?

Well, yeah, I misread the details. But not all books require identities in rings, hence the existence of the term "unital ring."

Hint: Think of the ring of Quaternions. They do form an algebra over $\mathbb{R}$, but what about over $\mathbb{C}$?

Any such ring for which the field $k$ is not in the centre of the ring.  Do you require the ring to be commutative ? If not, in comment @Mark above (quaternions over $\mathbf{C}$ should provide an example).

If $R$ is commutative and contains $k$, it follows that $R$ is necessarily a $k$-algebra.

Thank you for the explanations

It sounds like you are not requiring any connection between $R$ as a ring and $R$ as a $k$-vector space. If that is so, you can just pick an arbitrary ring structure and an arbitrary $k$-vector space structure on some set $X$ whose cardinality admits a $k$-vector space structure.. I think you need to clarify your question.

A natural way to produce this situation is for $K$ to be a subring of $R$. Then $R$ is a $K$-vector space with scalar multiplication given by left multiplication by $K$, but (exercise) $R$ is a $K$-algebra with this scalar multiplication iff $K$ is central. So it suffices to produce examples of rings $R$ equipped with subrings $K$ which are fields but which are not central.
Here is a general construction for producing many examples. Let $K$ be a field and let $G$ be a group (more generally, a monoid) acting on $K$ such that $g \in G$ acts via the map $\varphi_g : K \to K$. Then we can construct the crossed product $R = K \rtimes G$; this is a variation of the group algebra $K[G]$ in which the multiplication satisfies
$$gcg^{-1} = \varphi_g(c), g \in G, c \in K.$$
The result is a ring and a $K$-vector space but not a $K$-algebra unless the action of $G$ is trivial (because the above relation prevents the elements of $K$ from commuting with every element of $G$). Some examples:

Take $K/F$ to be a finite Galois extension with Galois group $G$. Then $K \rtimes G$ naturally acts on $K$ and this action is $F$-linear; this produces a map $K \rtimes G \to \text{End}_F(K) \cong M_n(F)$ where $n = [K : F]$, and this map turns out to be an isomorphism. Here the embedding $K \to M_n(F)$ comes from the action of $K$ on itself by left multiplication, and it makes $M_n(F)$ a $K$-vector space but not a $K$-algebra unless $n = 1$.
Take $G = \mathbb{Z}$ acting on any $K$ via powers of some automorphism $\varphi_1 : K \to K$. Then $K \rtimes \mathbb{Z}$ is a skew Laurent polynomial ring. We get a skew polynomial ring by taking $G = \mathbb{N}$ in the generalization to monoids.

A further variation of this construction can be used to produce the quaternions starting from the action of $G = C_2$ on $K = \mathbb{C}$ by complex conjugation, which is also an example as mentioned by Mark in the comments; see Wikipedia.
